# The role of halogens in electrophilic aromatic substitution

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds, halides, carbocation

I'm trying to understand what halogens do in electrophilic aromatic substitution. Consider the following.

Bromobenzene is introduced to a carbocation. Bromobenzene will likely react, but at a slower rate than unsubstituted benzene, because the bromine is inductively withdrawing. The bromine is also *not* resonance donating/activating, but can stabilize the intermediate product through resonance donation.

The bromine is an ortho/para director, **but** not because it donates electron density to these positions. Rather, when bromobenzene attacks a carbocation, the meta positions are formally positive, and through resonance donation, bromine *can* complete an octet in one of the resonance depictions.

[image]

Is this an accurate depiction of what a halogen does to benzene?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The bromine is also not resonance donating/activating

You can't have it both ways.  If the bromine can resonance interact with the intermediate, then it can also resonance interact in the starting bromobenzene.

Let's back up to the starting bromobenzene.

> Bromobenzene will likely react, but at a slower rate than plain
>   benzene, because the bromine is inductively withdrawing

That's correct, but let's compare further.  The oxygen in phenol is electron withdrawing (oxygen's electronegativity is even greater than bromine's), yet phenol is a very reactive aromatic compound towards electrophilic aromatic substitution (it will decolorize a solution of bromine, it doesn't even need a Lewis acid catalyst).  The difference between bromobenzene and phenol is that the phenolic oxygen can interact strongly *via* resonance and donate electrons into the aromatic ring, while the bromine in bromobenzene also resonance interacts with the aromatic ring, but much less efficiently (the larger size of bromine's $\ce{4p}$ orbitals makes overlap much less efficient with carbon's 2p orbitals).  Although the interaction is much less efficient, there still is some resonance interaction between the bromine substituent and the ring.  Look at the analogous resonance structures for bromobenzene that you drew for the intermediate, in the contest between inductive deactivation and weak resonance activation, the *ortho* and *para* positions are the **least deactivated**.

[image]

When bromobenzene undergoes electrophilic aromatic substitution, the whole ring is deactivated because (unlike phenol, where the resonance effect overwhelms the inductive effect) the weak resonance effect doesn't offset the strong inductive effect.  However, since the bromine substituent does interact with the *ortho* and *para* positions by resonance, these two positions are less deactivated that the *meta* position which cannot interact *via* resonance with the bromine substituent.

Comment: So two competing effects? @ron - induction vs resonance? But still not enough induction to completely deactivate benzene from reacting, unlike with a nitro group (both inductively and resonance deactivating)?

Comment: @Dissenter  That is exactly right, enough inductive deactivation to make all positions react slower than benzene, enough resonance activation to differentiate the ortho and para positions from the meta position. Nice analogy with nitrobenzene!

Comment: thank you; so any substituted benzene will react with a halonium ion, but not any substituted benzene will react in a Fridel crafts alkylation or acylation?

Comment: No, I don't think so.  Just as some substituted aromatics are to deactivated to react in a Friedel-Crafts reaction, I suspect there are also some very deactivated aromatics that won't react with halonium ions.

Comment: In a FC reaction if we have an exclusive meta director then the benzene is deactivated for reactions, correct? @ron

Comment: @Dissenter Yes, that's correct.